# Do spells cast using the Cleric's ACF Spontaneous Domain Casting qualify as casting a domain spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, optimization, cleric, alternate-class-feature

### Premise

This is a viability check for a cleric I am making with plans to move into the Radiant Servant of Pelor PrC. I'm trying to maximize the utility of a class feature and believe I found a non feat intensive method of getting more mileage out of it.

---

### Info Dump / Context

**Spontaneous Domain Casting - PHB II (p. 37)**

> Level: 1st.
>
> Replaces: If you select this class feature, you do not gain the
> ability to spontaneously convert prepared spells into cure or inflict
> spells.
>
> Benefit: You can convert stored spell energy into the spells of one of
> your domains. Pick one of your two domains. You can "lose" any
> prepared spell (other than a domain spell) to cast any spell of the
> same level or lower on that domain list. Your choice is permanent
> unless an alignment change, deity change, or other dramatic event
> leaves you incapable of accessing the domain.
>
> In addition, when preparing spells you can choose to fill any or all
> of your domain spell slots with either cure or inflict spells
> (depending on whether you would normally convert prepared spells to
> cure or inflict spells) of the same level.
>
> For example, Crucius is a cleric of Heironeous with the Good and War
> domains. At 1st level, he chooses to spontaneously cast War domain
> spells. Thereafter, he can lose a prepared 1st-level spell to cast
> magic weapon, a prepared 2nd-level spell to cast spiritual weapon (or
> magic weapon), and so on. Furthermore, in each domain spell slot he
> can prepare a spell from the Good domain, a spell from the War domain,
> or a cure spell of the same level.

- It should be noted that this is different from the spontaneous domain Feat.
- For our purposes we are giving up our spontaneous cure spells for
  spontaneous Healing Domain spells.

**Radiant Servant of Pelor - Empower / Maximize Healing(CD p. 52)**

> When a radiant servant of Pelor of at least 2nd [6th] level casts a domain
> spell from the Healing domain, that spell is affected as though by the
> Empower [Maximize] Spell feat. This spell does not use up a higher-level slot.

**Touch of Healing (CC p. 62)**

> As long as you have a conjuration (healing) spell of 2nd level or higher available to cast, you can spend a standard action to touch a target creature and heal 3 points of damage per level of the highest-level conjuration (healing) spell you have available to cast.

---

### What are we trying to do?

Free up all of our prepared slots for more useful stuff than raw healing - while being able to sacrifice a prepared spell for "Emergency" empowered (or maximized) healing.  We have Touch of Healing and a wand of lessor vigor in the backpack for out of combat healing.

---

### The Questions

- Do the spontaneously cast Healing Domain Spells using a prepared slot meet the requirements for the empowered healing feat?
- Does the ability to spontaneously cast a Healing Domain "Cure" spell meet the requirement for Touch of Healing?

Comment: Hello! I edited your question for better performance (I hope so : ) ). If I assidiently changed the meaning of some parts of it feel free to roll back my edit. Have a good time at RPG SE!

Comment: Ty Sir, I have no qualms with peeps doing markups on my questions / answers.  My spelling and grammar are, non-optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Touch of Healing: Definitely Yes

Getting the easy part out of the way first. If you can spontaneously cast a Conjuration (Healing) spell, and have a spell slot available in which to do so, you have it “available” as required by Touch of Healing. The fact that you have something else currently prepared in that slot doesn’t matter in the least when you can ditch that whenever you want.

Otherwise, Touch of Healing would fail entirely for favored souls, and I don’t think anyone wants to make that case.

### Empowered/Maximized Healing

#### RAW, probably Yes

Unfortunately, the rules not only fail to delineate exactly what a “domain spell” is or is not, but also use that phrase to refer to two related, but subtly different, things.

That is, we have that

> Each domain gives the cleric access to a domain spell at each spell level he can cast, from 1st on up...

> If a domain spell is not on the cleric spell list, a cleric can prepare it only in his domain spell slot.

where “domain spell” is used to refer to each of the spells on your domain lists, as unprepared, almost abstract concepts—potential spells you have the option of preparing and casting, but before we get to those steps. Tellingly, it says “Each domain” has—or, more accurately, “grants access to,”—a domain spell per spell level—that is important because most clerics have more than one domain, so we are talking about more than one domain spell per spell level. The latter quote here clearly indicates that “domain spell” as a phrase can refer to any of the spells on domain lists, even if they aren’t yet prepared—because it specifies where you can prepare them, which is meaningless if you’ve already done so.

Contrast that with

> A cleric also gets one domain spell of each spell level he can cast, starting at 1st level.

Here we’re taking about a real, tangible thing, a prepared spell, that the cleric could cast, or, say, a spellthief could steal. And you only get one of this kind of “domain spell” per spell level *per day*, unlike the other meaning of that phrase where you got (access to) one for “Each domain,” and there is no “per day” involved because your access to them is permanent and constant. This one domain spell per day is the result of taking the access to domain spells provided by our domain, and preparing them in our domain slot:

> When a cleric prepares a spell in a domain spell slot, it must come from one of his two domains (see Deities, Domains, and Domain Spells, below).

(For context, this sentence immediately follows the previous quote. Note that the “Deities, Domains, and Domain Spells” section referenced here is the source of the first two quotations in this answer.)

So we have two subtly-different meanings of the term “domain spell” here—one refers to any and all spells found on domains, and the other refers to the one spell per level per day you can prepare in your domain slot and cast, and both are just “domain spell.” Herein lies our real problem—which of these two meanings of the phrase is radiant servant of Pelor using? Radiant servant of Pelor, itself, doesn’t really give us a lot to go on either way.

However, there is a context that is very important: the one place where “domain spell” is definitively used to refer to the actual prepared-and-cast spell is in a paragraph that is all about discussing how many spells of each level a cleric can cast per day. That is, what they’re discussing here actually is your one “domain spell” *per day* of each level. In this sense, a “spell per day” is different from a “spell,” in that your “spells per day” (for each spell level) is the number that your domain spells ability adds +1 to, while the “spell” is the actual, ya know, spell, found on the domain list.

Also, importantly, that one time “domain spell” is used to refer to that one spell per day per level is in the spells section—and immediately refers you to the “Deities, Domains, and Domain Spells” section for more details. The section that includes “Domain Spells” in the title, and to which everything else directs you for information about domain spells, uses the term solely to refer to the spells on your domains’ lists, and *not* your one extra spell per day per spell level that is prepared in your domain slot.

Therefore, it seems to me, that the most likely definition for “domain spell” is “a spell found on your domains,” and **not** (necessarily and solely) “a spell prepared in your domain slot.” The use of that phrase in the cleric’s spells ability is actually (in context) the result of eliding the “per day” that was already under discussion, and which is indeed limited to one per spell level that corresponds to whatever you decide to put into your domain slot for each level. It is therefore very likely that “properly speaking,” RAW, the radiant servant of Pelor is referring to any spell of the Healing domain list, regardless of how it is cast.

#### But a strong circumstantial for No being the intent

But we should go back to the radiant servant of Pelor at this point, because while it doesn’t give us a **lot** to go on, there may be something:

> When a radiant servant of Pelor of at least 2nd [6th] level casts a domain spell from the Healing domain, that spell is affected as though by the Empower [Maximize] Spell feat. This spell does not use up a higher-level slot.

If we understand “domain spell” to refer to those spells you got access to because of the domains you have, the use of that phrase here would be entirely redundant with “spell from the Healing domain,” since of course (near-tautologically) a spell from the Healing domain is a spell from a domain. Furthermore, radiant servant of Pelor here is emphasizing that you *cast* the domain spell, which isn’t *quite* something you can do with a spell on a list—you have to prepare it in a slot, and then it is the *prepared spell* that you cast. This is a lot closer to what the spells section is talking about when it says “A cleric also gets one domain spell of each spell level he can cast,” since that prepared spell is the physical manifestation of that extra spell per day (per spell level) that the cleric gets. That makes for a strong, if circumstantial, case for thinking that the authors of radiant servant of Pelor may not have been as careful about this as we may have liked, and were referring specifically to the one prepared in your domain slot.

On top of this, spontaneous domain casting *itself* even states you cannot use “a domain spell” to spontaneously cast another spell from your chosen domain. again, that only makes sense if they’re talking about the spell prepared in your domain slot—otherwise any spell available from one of your domains, or maybe even from *any* domain, would be ineligible for being spontaneously converted to one of the spells from your chosen domain, and that certainly doesn’t seem likely at all.

#### How things work out in each case:

If a “domain spell” is any spell you get access to from a domain, as RAW seems to indicate, then you can use spontaneous domain casting to cast it and it’s still a domain spell, but then at that point you could have just prepared it to begin with (or, in the case of most Healing domain spells, spontaneously cast them using the core cleric spontaneous casting feature).

If a domain spell is specifically the spell prepared in the domain slot—which, again, it probably isn’t RAW, but there’s evidence here that both the authors of radiant servant of Pelor and spontaneous domain casting itself thought it was—then spontaneous domain casting doesn’t really help. Nothing in the ACF specifies that the process of spontaneously casting one of these spells with the ACF made it into a domain spell.

#### On balance: I’d allow it

It seems pretty clear to me that the authors were **not** clear on what exactly “domain spell” as a term should refer to. Furthermore, radiant servant of Pelor is a pretty garbage prestige class, and the empowered and maximized healing features are extremely poor. At the end of the day, the **real** answer is the one that makes for the best game, and **that** at least is quite clear: *cure* spells need all the help they can get, and someone dedicating themselves to those spells does likewise. Frankly, I’d nix all mention of “domain spell” from radiant servant of Pelor and allow those features to apply to any of the spells from the Healing domain, regardless of how or when you cast them. So you shouldn’t even need the spontaneous domain casting ACF for it (though you may want it since a few of those spells are superior to the *cure* spell you’d otherwise be able to cast spontaneously).

Answer (score -1):

## Do the spontaneously cast Healing Domain Spells using a prepared slot meet the requirements for the empowered healing feat?

A: **No**

Per the [cleric spell rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/cleric.htm#deityDomainsandDomainSpells):

> Each domain gives the cleric access to a domain spell at each spell level he can cast, from 1st on up...

Only the "domain spell," meaning the one-per-spell-level-per-day spells that cannot be used for spontaneous casting, can be empowered for free. This is different than spells belonging to a domain. Although you gain the ability to cast spells of one of your domains spontaneously, you do not gain additional "domain spells."

### Relevant Domain Spell Rules Clarifications

I see a lot of confusion in the comments about domain spells, so here's a breakdown:

- **Domain Spell**: *"A cleric also gets one domain spell of each spell level he can cast, starting at 1st level."*
  - When referring to casting a *domain spell*, this is the spell that fills a *domain spell slot*
  - When referring to a domain spell list of sorts, this refers to a *potential* domain spell: *"Each domain gives the cleric access to a domain spell at each spell level he can cast, from 1st on up, as well as a granted power."* Again, this merely grants access to a domain spell.
- **Domain Spells** (plural): *"With access to two domain spells at a given spell level, a cleric prepares one or the other each day in his domain spell slot."* Again, this refers to the available domain spells, one of which can be prepared in the *domain spell slot*
- **Domain Spell Slot**: *"When a cleric prepares a spell in a domain spell slot, it must come from one of his two domains..."*
- Note that a cleric can only prepare a domain spell in a domain spell slot. That is the only way provided in the rules for a domain spell to be prepared.
- Also note that **Spontaneous Domain Casting** allows a cure or inflict spell to also be prepared into a *domain spell slot*. This might turn these in to domain spells -- that would be an answer for a different question. Otherwise, the cleric can prepare all cure spells, then possibly substitute in spells from the domain spell list into those slots spontaneously.

This line from the **Spontaneous Domain Casting** line is also important:

> *"You can "lose" any prepared spell (other than a domain spell) to cast any spell of the same level or lower on that domain list."*

This clarifies that you are not casting domain spells from the chosen domain list, you are casting spells from that list. You also expressly cannot spontaneously cast from domain spells which, as previously noted, are spells prepared in a domain spell slot.

A *domain spell* is a specific, defined thing. It can overlap with the cleric's normal list of available spells, but a spell is not a domain spell unless it is one of the spells that is prepared into a domain spell slot.

## Does the ability to spontaneously cast a Healing Domain "Cure" spell meet the requirement for Touch of Healing?

A: **Yes**

*Touch of Healing* does not require a spell to be prepared, just available to cast. Since your spontaneous casting would allow for you to cast a spell, the requirement is satisfied.

Comment: -1: The passage you quoted continues with: "If a domain spell is not on the cleric spell list, a cleric can prepare it only in his domain spell slot." So, it is still a domain spell, even if it isn't prepared in domain spell slot.

Comment: @annoyingimp specific vs general. The feat grants the capability to prepare spells from the domain spell list. It does not grant additional domain spells which have a specific definition.

Comment: 'If a domain spell is on the cleric spell list, a cleric can prepare it in any of his spell slots.' is the reversed case of what I quoted first. It clearly says, domain spell, even if prepared in non-domain spell slot, is still a domain spell, doesn't it?

Comment: @annoyingimp no. That line is merely pointing out that the presence of a spell as a domain spell does not restrict a cleric from only memorizing it as a domain spell rather than an ordinary spell. I.e. cure light wounds can be memorized in normal spell slots even if it is also the level 1 domain spell. It doesn't change that there is only one domain spell per spell level.

Comment: @annoyingimp another way to look at it: a domain spell cannot be chosen for spontaneous casting: *The cleric can "lose" any prepared spell that is not a domain spell in order to cast...* This makes it clear, otherwise no cleric could substitute a cure/inflict spell for any spell from their domain spell list

Comment: OK, I agree there is an inconsistency in the rules on this subject. While I still disagree, there is no way to clearly back up one or another point of view without speculation. I'll remove -1 on opportunity, right now it is locked.

Comment: This answer incorrectly conflates “domain spell” and “domain slot.” In particular, the very first quote describing a “domain spell” describe it as something you get from *each* domain—that is, with two domains, you get *two* domain spells per spell level—but clerics only get one domain *slot* of each spell level, and have to pick *which* of the two (usually) domain spells they have for that level are going in the one slot that day. Since the rest of the answer follows from the idea that “domain spell” refers to the “domain slot,” none of it is supported.

Comment: What this answer needs is something saying something like “you can only prepare a domain spell in a domain slot,” which would make it clearer that even if you have the same spell on your list and prepare it in other slots, those don’t count as the domain spell. That would still require some effort to determine whether or not spontaneous domain casting would be an exception, though...

Comment: I am watching this "Thread" and can see the arguments to both sides (which is why I asked the question).  I do appreciate the dialogue going on here.  <3

Comment: @kryan no. The domain spell slot is the spell slot allocated to the domain spell. A cleric gets one domain spell per spell level per day which fills the domain spell slot. The domain spell is a defined thing here.

Comment: That is demonstrably false. A cleric typically gets two domain spells per spell level, though any number 0–3 is possible—it just matches the number of domains they have. Each domain gives one per spell level. And no per day involved; you don’t expend domain spells, just the slot to prepare them in and cast them from. Of at least so say the quotes you have included in this answer.

Comment: @annoyingimp I updated the answer to include additional info.

Comment: "You can convert stored spell energy into the spells of one of your domains." - With the ACF our cure spells are being spontaneously cast as a Domain Spell. Spell of our domain = domain spell?  Were no longer spontaneously casting a cure spell, but spontaneously casting a Healing Domain spell...  Or at least that's the crux of the argument to allow for spontaneous empowered / maximized.  But your argument is that domain spells only come from the domain slots.  Correct?

Comment: @PlayPatrice it does not say that you spontaneously cast a domain spell from one of your domains, though. It says you spontaneously cast a spell from one of your domains. Just like cure light wounds is a spell in the healing domain domain spells. It's like a Venn diagram of spells and domain spells

Comment: Ah, I see some of the confusion: some of the rules refer to the prepared spell in the domain slot as a “domain spell,” eliding the “prepared.” Unfortunately very common. However, since literally the very next thing you quote also uses “domain spell” to refer to the spells you could prepare from each domain, you need to justify the implicit claim that empowered healing means the former and not the latter—particularly since the latter is your “primary” quote up front, which it simply shouldn’t be. I can sort of see an argument for your case here based on “cast” in RSoP, but it’s tricky.

Comment: Also, “A spell cannot be a domain spell unless it is prepared into a domain spell slot,” does not follow from the quote that this is supposed to be an analysis of. The quoted text actually states the converse of that—that a spell must be a domain spell in order to go into that slot, not (necessarily) that it must go into that slot in order to be a domain spell. (Actually, even saying that much requires reading the word “domain” in between the lines where the quote just says “a spell.”) This is a [converse fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @KRyan is there something I missing where a domain spell is defined differently than what I say my answer? Because something cannot be used as a domain spell unless a method for such is provided in the rules. As you sometimes point out in answers, one of the reasons people can't use something is because the rules have not allowed for it, and one can't do anything that the rules do not allow for.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock See my answer, where I have taken advantage of the greater space to explain in more detail. In short, there are two separate meanings of the phrase “domain spell,” and you’re mixing them up. Your conclusion is probably sound—at least contextually, as likely intended by the authors—but your analysis for determining that conclusion is flawed.